# How to remove a background of a JPG image given another PNG image with an object in it?

Tags: node.js, d3.js

For example, I have a PNG image where there is an object I need (not transparent) and a background area (transparent). I would like to cut the same object (non-transparent area) from another JPG image to a new PNG.

```
let jpg = d3.select("#myJpg"); 
let png = d3.select("#myPng");

// cut object of png from jpg
```

Comment: You can create a canvas, draw the PNG, then use a `compositeOperation` to only fill the pixels of the PNG when you draw the JPEG over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using canvas you can cut out on image using another, but there are some serious restrictions here (your image *needs* to be hosted on your server or have the correct `CORS` header for you canvas to export data - if you don't need to export the image to a DataURL it should be fine).

```js
void async function(){

  const canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
  const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
  const firstImage = await testImageSquare( 400, 400, 200, 'red' );
  const secondImage = await testImageSquare( 400, 400, 100, 'green' );

  canvas.width = firstImage.naturalWidth;
  canvas.height = firstImage.naturalHeight;

  ctx.drawImage( firstImage, 0, 0 );
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
  ctx.drawImage( secondImage, 0, 0 );

  document.body.append( firstImage, secondImage, canvas );

}();

/** Helper method to create images */
async function testImageSquare( width, height, squareSize, fillStyle ){

  const canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
  const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
  
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  
  ctx.fillStyle = fillStyle;
  ctx.fillRect( (width - squareSize) / 2, (height - squareSize) / 2, squareSize, squareSize );
  
  const image = new Image;
  
  image.src = canvas.toDataURL();
  
  await new Promise(r => image.addEventListener( 'load', r ));
  
  return image;
  
}
```

```css
img, canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```